# Typescript Knockout Validation custom rule

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I want to write a custom rule for Knockout-Validation library (https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) using Typescript. I have a .ts file and i'm trying to out this code:

```
export function enableCustomValidators() {
    ko.validation.rules["myRule"] = {
        validator: function (val: string, otherVal: string) {
            return val === otherVal;
    },
    message: 'The field must equal {0}',
}

    ko.validation.registerExtenders();
}
```

At build time I am receiving this error: **Error    TS7017  Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'KnockoutValidationRuleDefinitions' has no index signature.**

What's the correct way to add a new custom validator using Typescript?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely an issue with the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/knockout.validation/index.d.ts#L144) which does not have an indexer to add custom validations. You can augment the `KnockoutValidationRuleDefinitions` interface temporarily in your code:

```
declare global {
    interface KnockoutValidationRuleDefinitions {
        [customValidationRuleName: string]: KnockoutValidationRuleDefinition
    }
}
```

Or explicitly cast `ko.validation.rules` as `any` to silence the compiler:

```
(ko.validation.rules as any)["myRule"] = {
    validator: function (val: string, otherVal: string) {
        return val === otherVal;
    },
    message: 'The field must equal {0}',
}
```

If you want this fixed in the type definitions itself you can raise a PR against the [DefinitelyTyped reporitory](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/knockout.validation/index.d.ts#L144) with the indexer added to the `KnockoutValidationRuleDefinitions` interface.